# How to stop Multi-Drag in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

> I am developing an application using drag and drop but I want only
>   one drag at a time on the screen or only one feedback is shown on the
>   screen. When I am using 2 fingers to drag to boxes both feedback are
>   shown on the screen. What I have done is if one drag is on the screen
>   then other boxes are not draggable but If you tap at the same time on
>   two boxes both box are draggable. How to stop these drags?
>   [Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNlfo.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Drag Box'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(title),
      ),
      body:
          new DragGame(), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class DragGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DragGameState createState() => new _DragGameState();
}

class _DragGameState extends State<DragGame> {
  int boxNumberIsDragged;

  @override
  void initState() {
    boxNumberIsDragged = null;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildDraggableBox(1, Colors.red, new Offset(30.0, 100.0)),
            buildDraggableBox(2, Colors.yellow, new Offset(30.0, 200.0)),
            buildDraggableBox(3, Colors.green, new Offset(30.0, 300.0)),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget buildDraggableBox(int boxNumber, Color color, Offset offset) {
    return new Draggable(
      maxSimultaneousDrags: boxNumberIsDragged == null || boxNumber == boxNumberIsDragged ? 1 : 0,
      child: _buildBox(color, offset),
      feedback: _buildBox(color, offset),
      childWhenDragging: _buildBox(color, offset, onlyBorder: true),
      onDragStarted: () {
        setState((){
          boxNumberIsDragged = boxNumber;
        });
      },
      onDragCompleted: () {
        setState((){
          boxNumberIsDragged = null;
        });
      },
      onDraggableCanceled: (_,__) {
        setState((){
          boxNumberIsDragged = null;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBox(Color color, Offset offset, {bool onlyBorder: false}) {
    return new Container(
      height: 50.0,
      width: 50.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: offset.dx, top: offset.dy),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: !onlyBorder ? color : Colors.grey,
          border: Border.all(color: color)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `maxSimultaneousDrags`?

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html

Edit 1:
**onDragStarted** is fired only when user started moving the finger. What you need is onTap.

Edit 2:
Please change to **onTap** => **onTapDown**. Also use setState to reconstruct the two other widgets when one widget is **"tapDowned"**. Tested on my device. See if this works for you. Good luck.

```
Widget buildDraggableBox(int boxNumber, Color color, Offset offset) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      child: Draggable(
        maxSimultaneousDrags: boxNumberIsDragged == null || boxNumber == boxNumberIsDragged ? 1 : 0,
        child: _buildBox(color, offset),
        feedback: _buildBox(color, offset),
        childWhenDragging: _buildBox(color, offset, onlyBorder: true),
        onDragStarted: () {
          setState((){

          });
        },
        onDragCompleted: () {
          setState((){
            boxNumberIsDragged = null;
          });
        },
        onDraggableCanceled: (_,__) {
          setState((){
            boxNumberIsDragged = null;
          });
        },
      ),
      onTapDown: (_) {
          setState(() {
            boxNumberIsDragged = boxNumber;
      });
    )
  }
```

Comment: no maxSimultaneousDrags is work for only one draggable box.

Comment: Wow, your use case is sure specific. Try onTapDown then. I have updated your code.

Comment: @axelblaze I know this is old but I have the same problem and it doesn't seem to work for me because if you press on both at the same time you can still drag both

Answer (score 0):

I faced to the same issue and I soved using external `bool allowDragging = false;` variable to disable multi drag:

```
Draggable(
    maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
    onDragUpdate: (drag){
    },
    allowedButtonsFilter: (int){
      return !allowDragging;
    },
    onDragStarted: (){
      if(!allowDragging){
        setState(() {
          allowDragging = true;
          selected = words.elementAt(index);
        });
      }
    },
    onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset){
      setState(() {
        allowDragging = false;
      });
    },
    onDragEnd: (info){
      if(!info.wasAccepted){
      }
    },
    data: words.elementAt(index),
    feedback: Text(words.elementAt(index).text),
    child: Text(words.elementAt(index).text)

)
```

Hope this help :p